# Bootstrap table rowspan need dynamically

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have used Bootstrap 3 for the table format , i need to add row in a dynamically with php but showing some misalignment, I have used row span 9, but need dynamic row ...Kindly review my html code and clear this issues....

```
<textarea name="textarea" rows="2" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Goals"></textarea>
<table border="1" class="table" >
<tr>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
<th width="15%">Goals</th>
<th width="15%">Comments</th>
<th width="10%">UOM</th>
<th width="10%">Weights</th>
<th width="10%">Pre. Year</th>
<th width="10%">Curr. Year</th>
<th width="10%">CYA</th>
<th width="10%">Achievements</th>
<th width="10%">Comments</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" rowspan="9" class="first" ><br>
Financial <span class="addrow"> <i class="addplus fa fa-plus"></i> Add Goal </span> </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Commands"></textarea></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="UOM"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Weights"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY14"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY15"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY16"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Achievements"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Goals"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Commands"></textarea></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="UOM"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Weights"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY14"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY15"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY16"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Achievements"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Goals"></textarea>
</td>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Commands"></textarea></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="UOM"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Weights"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY14"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY15"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY16"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Achievements"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Goals"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Commands"></textarea></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="UOM"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Weights"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY14"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY15"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY16"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Achievements"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Goals"></textarea>
</td>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Commands"></textarea></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="UOM"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Weights"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY14"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY15"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY16"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Achievements"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Goals"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Commands"></textarea></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="UOM"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Weights"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY14"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY15"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY16"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Achievements"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Goals"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Commands"></textarea></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="UOM"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Weights"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY14"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY15"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY16"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Achievements"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Goals"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Commands"></textarea></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="UOM"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Weights"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY14"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY15"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="FY16"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Achievements"></td>
<td class="colum"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments"></td>
```

Comment: Looking good ! but if you need it dynamically, row span should be dynamic or if you have a fixed no of rows then it will work fine.

Comment: Just ran your code on snippet one cell is missing because of this <td>&nbsp;</td> after row span.If you need me to attach the snippet I will do.